# Best way to store large amounts of text? Outside of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am installing a new mail system on my site and for the message body text i dont want to store it using MySql as it will just slow my server down, so i am thinking of storing it as .txt files on the server and using MySql to point at it and using

`file_get_contents('file.txt');` to open it and maybe using `BASE64` to encode the contents so its not plain text.

Would this be the best way to store the text or is there a better to store it?

Comment: If only there were some software dedicated to reliably storing and quickly retrieving large amounts of indexed data. Oh wait...

Comment: So as a speed advantage over mysql youre going to use mysql, the filesystem and base64?

Comment: @bkconrad What are you alluding to?

Comment: Bkconrad is alluding to the fact that "some software dedicated to reliably storing and quickly retrieving large amounts of text" = mySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking it all wrong.
Storing the message body in mysql will **not** slow your server down.

> is there a better to store it?

Sure. Store it in the database. That is what databases are for.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to achieve. Have you tested that MySQL is too slow? You might be surprised.

Your approach seems ok, except additionally, you could gzip the text. Gzip is very fast, and will provide decent compression on emails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why storing it in mysql would slow your site down. I think that would be the preferred way to store it. However, if you want to store it text files then plain text should be find. Maybe use gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is? If it's body text for an email that is to be sent repetitively or to a large volume of recipients, store the text/HTML string in a text file.

The only reason I could see it being useful to store it in a database is if you wanted the templates to be editable by admins via a content management system or similar.